# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight is invalid redirect in angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am using `angular2` and calling a web api using below method to post data.

and getting error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight is invalid redirect

```
public _apiPath: string = 'http://myapplicationapi.azurewebsites.net/';
post(data?: any, mapJson: boolean = true) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('dataType', 'jsonp');

    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    var uri;

    if (this._pageIndex) {
       uri = this._baseUri + '?pageIndex=' + this._pageIndex.toString() + '&pageSize=' + this._pageSize.toString();
    } else {
        uri = this._baseUri;
    }

    if (mapJson) {

        return this.http.post(uri, data, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(responce => <any>(<Response>responce).json());

    } else {
        return this.http.post(uri, data, {
            headers: headers
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to fix this on the server. The server doesn't respond properly to CORS requests. CORS kicks in when the IP or port where you load your Angular application and where you make the HTTP request are different.

Comment: in the server i have used below on the controller  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Comment: Can you please send me the file name where you made changes and your problem is solved? I am new and don't know what actually controller is located and where to change.